# What kind of spider is this, please?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I've found this spider in my bathroom today, never seen one like this, especially since I'm living in part of Europe ( Bosnia, Balkans ) that isn't known for being promised land for spiders. This one was somehow aggressive, when I touched him with an object, he immediately launched himself from the roof using his net, and when landed, he raised his "bottom"?! I've sprayed him with some water, and removed him as seen on picture, didn't want to kill him, but I'm interested if this is some venomous kind, because his head was blood red, and I've never seen this in my region

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems to be an Araniella Cucurbitina ,also called a cucumber spider. It grows upto 4mm to 6mm. This type is native to the UK and they have venom which is not considered dangerous to humans.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! When answering identification questions inclusion of an uploaded image for comparison will help you get a more favorable response to your posting. If you can provide details (ideally with references) for what characters led you to this identification that would be even better. ——— You may also wish to take the tour: biology.stackexchange.com/tour and then consult the help pages on the standards for how to effectively provide answers — see: biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. Thanks! 

Comment: looks more like a kind of sac spider to me